# Parse the css pseudo element content from regex

Tags: javascript, css, regex, pseudo-element, regex-negation

I am parsing the content of css pseudo element in javascript.

Content is

```
counter(item, decimal), ' ', fdgsdf, attr(data), counter(item1,lower-alpha)
```

expected output

```
[counter(item, decimal),' ',fdgsdf, attr(data),counter(item1,lower-alpha) ]
```

Currently i am using below regex

```
/(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|([^']*)|(?:counter|attr|url)\(([^)]*)\))/gi
```

The problem is with text content. I want text and other (url,attr,counter) to be separate match.
How can i match above string and generate equivalent array of match elements to process further

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Zenoo added expected output in question

Comment: Try `\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|((?:counter|attr|url)\((?:[^)]*)\))|([^,]+))`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/ckmZqz/1

Comment: @revo not working for this input "counter(item, decimal), '', fdgsdf, attr(data), url(file:///Users/tiwpavan/workspace/input/test.jpeg), counters(item, ' ', decimal)"

Comment: Because it should be `counter` and not `counters`?

Comment: actually counters is also an valid css pseudo element property

Comment: So you should tell the regex engine to match it too. Change `counter` to `counters?`

Comment: /\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|((?:counter|counters|attr|url)\((?:[^)]*)\))|([^,]+))/ new regex but the problem is, input string is insie double quotes but content are escaped by single quotes. "counter-increment:section 1;content:counters(section, '.', decimal), '\''" Now last string matches the content "'\''". actually it should be "'" only.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the functions' names, you can use the RegEx [`\w+(?:\([^)]*\))?|'[^']*'|"[^"]*"`](https://regex101.com/r/5pJT92/2)

- `\w+` matches a word character 1 or more times
- `(?:\([^)]*\))?` matches the function parameters if there are some
- `'[^']*'` matches any String inside `''`
- `"[^"]*"` matches any String inside `""`

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/5pJT92/2)